# How to create Activity as this application

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview

I want to create app as this picture but i don't know how to do.

[image]

Comment: This is not easy. This picture has a lot of elements. Please, put your code and we'll try help you.

Comment: Thank you. I did drawer navigation, toolbar ok, but I don't know how to create listview or recyclerview with item 0 as header.

Comment: You should learn using android components

Comment: This is my app, but but I don't know how to create listview or recyclerview with item 0 as header

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-pM7lBFg8eNg/Vh9vVHjip5I/AAAAAAAAAs4/iQMRlh_PKIo/s512-Ic42/Screenshot_2015-10-15-16-16-48-47%25255B1%25255D.png

Comment: I responded in a new answer

Answer (score 0):

OK. So, now You need a linearLayout (orientation:vertical) and inside yout put imageview and textView.